# Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Philosophy Stack Exchange](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Proof of the reflexivity of the accessibility relation](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15019/proof-of-the-reflexivity-of-the-accessibility-relation)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What a "Bismarckian realist"](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15659/what-a-bismarckian-realist)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What are the axioms for quantified modal logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15409/what-are-the-axioms-for-quantified-modal-logic)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Do two moral values exist, such that both imply the other?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15281/do-two-moral-values-exist-such-that-both-imply-the-other)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Is the golden rule considered childish in philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15317/is-the-golden-rule-considered-childish-in-philosophy)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [How do we know if a mathematical proof is valid?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15336/how-do-we-know-if-a-mathematical-proof-is-valid)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Who owns the means of production?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15452/who-owns-the-means-of-production)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Is it ever right to act contrary to your moral principles?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15593/is-it-ever-right-to-act-contrary-to-your-moral-principles)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Does Descartes' cogito require awareness of thinking?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15411/does-descartes-cogito-require-awareness-of-thinking)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Tu quoque and scientific anti-philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/tu-quoque-and-scientific-anti-philosophy)

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 7)

---